# How to check a checkbox element according to the value in cypress while the value does not exist

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, css-selectors, cypress

How do I check a checkbox element according to the value in cypress, while the value attribute does not exist.
I want to check the checkbox according to the value, not the id, because the id is different for each page.

[image]

Because in some pages, the id starts with c1, and some page ids start with c2, and some start with c5.
How would I check the element according to value?
I got the selector for all 3 checkboxes, but it checked all the 3 elements. I want specific element according to value attribute, but there there is no value attribute.
i tried this

```
             cy.get('.x-overlay__wrapper--right input[type="checkbox"]').check()
```

but it checked all the element
and this checked the first element

```
             cy.get('.x-overlay__wrapper--right input[type="checkbox"]').first().check()
```

but I want the checked according to value, but here in attributes there is no value attribute.

the value that i want is just written next to checkbox

[image]

and here in html
[image]

Comment: Please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In other words, what have you already tried?

Comment: I posted an answer. Does the code work?

Comment: I updated to match your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the html, perhaps search for the text then use parent and sibling commands to shift the subject to the checkbox, something like

```
cy.contains('span', 'Free Shipping')  // find your text
  .parent('div')                      // move to parent div
  .siblings('span.checkbox')          // move to checkbox span
  .find('input')                      // select it's input
  .check();
```

Comment: cy.check() can only be called on :checkbox and :radio. Your subject is a: <span class="checkbox cbx x-refine__multi-select-checkbox ">...</span>Learn more

Comment: LOL - I saw the class checkbox and assumed that was the input. Obviously you will need to find the input within `span.checkbox`.

Answer (score 1):

Example with comments explaining the code:

```js
cy.get('.x-overlay__wrapper--right input[type="checkbox"]').each((checkbox, i) => { // Get the elements and run .each() on them
  if (cy.get('.cbx.x-refine__multi-select-cbx')[i].innerHTML === "value") { // If the value is something, perform an action. Replace "value" with the value that you need to test it for
    checkbox.check()
  }
})
```

Comment: from where i will get the value? the value is written next to checkbox

Comment: @leenM I  think I misunderstood you. By value, did you mean the text inside the input box?

Comment: i edited the question, i mean the value that next for each checkbox, for example free shipping, it is just written  next to the checkbox

Comment: @leenM Ok. I'll edit the question later to include that.

Comment: i have this error "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
"